# I made this calculator using JS, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this calculator using JS, but it's not working:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

function add() {
var result = num1 + num2;
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = result; }

function sub() {
var result = num1 - num2;
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = result; }

function mul() {
var result = num1 * num2;
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = result; }

function div() {
var result = num1 / num2;
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = result; }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(209, 100, 100);
}
h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
  } 

.num1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.681);
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 45px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
.num2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.681);
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 45px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }  

.add {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgray;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 54px;
    position: relative;
    top: 235px;
    right: 235px;
  } 

  .sub {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgray;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 54px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}  

.mul {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgray;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50px;
    }

    .div {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgray;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family:  'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    left: 330px;
    }

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 70px;
        position: relative;
        top: 100px;
        left: 10px;
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <input type="number" name="First Nummber" class="num1" id="firstNum">
    <input type="number" name="Second Nummber" class="num2" id="secondNum">


      <button onclick="add()" class="add">Add</button>
      <button onclick="sub()" class="sub">Subtract</button>
      <button onclick="mul()" class="mul">Multiply</button>
      <button onclick="div()" class="div">Divide</button>

      x<h2 id="ans"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

When I enter values and click on an operation, it just shows NaN

How do I fix this?

I realize this has something to do with the parseInt function but please specify what is going wrong.

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your element selector. Your input id is `firstNum` but you are targeting with `document.getElementById("num1")`.

Comment: I fixed it, but it is still not working

Comment: This is the error that I am getting:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at script.js:2:56